# How to conditionally set an html input value to blank

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a razor file containing the line:

```
<input type="hidden" class="personId" value=@(Model != null ? Model.Id : "") />
```

So I was aiming for when the Model exists set the value of the hidden control to the Id of the model. When it doesn't exist value="".

What I got was value="/"

So I tried instead:

```
<input type="hidden" class="personId" value=@(Model != null ? Model.Id : string.Empty)/>
```

Same result.

Tried:

```
<input type="hidden" class="personId" value=@(Model != null ? Model.Id : null)/>
```

Same again.

Why can't I set it to empty?

Is this even the right approach should I omit value all together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using a helper which is designed for this purpose:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id, new { @class = "personId" })
```

Comment: That would work except for the fact it's a partial view where a model isn't always passed in.

Comment: Yes the razor file has no @model at the top so it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, then put a model. How do you even expect to use the `Model` property which you are already using in your spaghetti version? Just put a `@model MyViewModel` and then use `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)` as I suggested you in my answer. Now you could pass null to the partial, no problem at all, the helper will do exactly what you expect it to do. Just try what I am saying, we will talk then.

Comment: Thank you, much better. Sorry was confused. Your way is much better.

Comment: Glad I could help. Is there something else you would like to ask on this topic or you might consider closing the question?